# Few pixels beetween sliverApp bar and the rest of my page

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-sliverappbar

I work on a flutter app to learn, however on my junnction beetween my sliver AppBar title and the rest of my page i have few pixels.

I try to put margin negative.

Do you have an idea how to remove it ?

[image: few pixel junction]

here is my code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:food_deliver/controllers/recommended_product_controller.dart';
import 'package:food_deliver/models/Popular_product_model.dart';
import 'package:food_deliver/routes/route_helper.dart';
import 'package:food_deliver/utils/app_constats.dart';
import 'package:food_deliver/utils/colors.dart';
import 'package:food_deliver/utils/dimensions.dart';
import 'package:food_deliver/widget/app_icon.dart';
import 'package:food_deliver/widget/big_text.dart';
import 'package:food_deliver/widget/expandable_text_widget.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class RecommendedFoodDetail extends StatelessWidget {
  final int pageId;
  const RecommendedFoodDetail({Key? key, required this.pageId})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ProductModel product =
        Get.find<RecommendedProductController>().recommendedProductList[pageId];

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: CustomScrollView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        slivers: [
          SliverAppBar(
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
            toolbarHeight: 80,
            title: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Get.toNamed(RouteHelper.getInitial());
                      },
                      child: AppIcon(iconData: Icons.close)),
                  AppIcon(iconData: Icons.shopping_bag_sharp)
                ]),
            bottom: PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(Dimensions.height20),
              child: Container(
                child: Center(
                    child: BigText(
                  text: product.name!,
                  size: Dimensions.height30,
                )),
                width: double.maxFinite,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 7, bottom: 7),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(Dimensions.width20),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(Dimensions.width20))),
              ),
            ),
            expandedHeight: 300,
            pinned: true,
            backgroundColor: AppColors.yellowColor,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              //title: Text("title"),
              background: Image(
                  image: NetworkImage(AppConstats.BASE_URL +
                      AppConstats.UPLOAD_URL +
                      product.img!),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover),
            ),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: Dimensions.width20, right: Dimensions.width20),
                  child: ExpandableTextWidget(text: product.description!))
            ],
          )),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              left: Dimensions.width20 * 3.5,
              right: Dimensions.width20 * 3.5,
              top: Dimensions.height10,
              bottom: Dimensions.height10),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              AppIcon(
                iconData: Icons.remove,
                backgroundColor: AppColors.mainColor,
                iconColor: Colors.white,
                iconSize: 30,
              ),
              BigText(
                text: "\$ ${product.price}  x  0",
                color: AppColors.mainBlackColor,
              ),
              AppIcon(
                iconData: Icons.add,
                backgroundColor: AppColors.mainColor,
                iconColor: Colors.white,
                iconSize: 30,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            top: Dimensions.height20,
            bottom: Dimensions.height20,
            left: Dimensions.width20,
            right: Dimensions.width20,
          ),
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                left: Dimensions.width10, right: Dimensions.width10),
            child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, right: 0),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: Dimensions.height20,
                        bottom: Dimensions.height20,
                        left: Dimensions.width20,
                        right: Dimensions.width20),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 230, 228, 228),
                        borderRadius:
                            BorderRadius.circular(Dimensions.radius20)),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.favorite,
                          color: AppColors.mainColor,
                          size: 25,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: Dimensions.height20,
                        bottom: Dimensions.height20,
                        left: Dimensions.width20,
                        right: Dimensions.width20),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: AppColors.mainColor,
                        borderRadius:
                            BorderRadius.circular(Dimensions.radius20)),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        BigText(
                          size: 22,
                          text: "\$ 10 Add to cart",
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ]),
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think There are many parts can be removed to reproduce the issue. you can check more about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple work around is to place everything inside a container with white background.

```
    return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
        child: Scaffold(
```